# Why were the aliens waiting on the other side of the gate in "Spirits of Flux and Anchor"?

Tags: jack-l-chalker

In the [*Soul Rider* series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jack_L._Chalker#The_Soul_Rider_series) featuring the book *Spirits of Flux and Anchor*, what exactly were the aliens waiting on the other side of the gate for?

Answer (score 2):

I am currently re-reading the series, but as I recall it.. it was not a "waiting". Just like when Toby left Earth, they were basically transformed into energy and beamed to the next location. The aliens were using a similar technology and intersected Toby's network and took over due to their superior knowledge of Flux. It was my understanding that they transmitted themselves down the line, expecting the next gate to be open and no challenge to them. There they were stuck in an energy transmission state.. not aging or knowing the passage of time.. like a living movie on perpetual pause.